# How to install oracle-java on ubuntu 12.04 behind a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, ubuntu-12.04, netbeans-7

I 'm use to work with Netbeans 7.2.1 on ubuntu 12.04. 
Since the update on july 24, it's no more possible to create projects with it. That comes from the update of the openjdk, as mentionned [on this topic](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic56099.html).

The more convenient solution seems to use oracle-java instead of open-jdk. Hopefully, there are plenty of docs explaining how to switch from one to the other.

Nevertheless, I encounter an issue while trying to install oracle-java7 on my ubuntu.

1. In a terminal I type in `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`
2. Up to there, everything is going well, but then, the **connection to *edelivery.oracle.com* fails** because timeout expires

I'm behind a company proxy, so I assume the problem may come from that. But I'have no clue how to resolve that.

Comment: You can download the file directly from oracle's website and install it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this alternative, but though I 'm curious to know what is wrong whith my apt configuration ?
Is apt trying to download on a blocked port for example ?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools **used primarily for programming**". How can you justify to put my question off-topic ? Is not Netbeans a tools **commonly used by programmers** ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Linux Mint, I don't like relying on apt to have Oracle Java, so I did this:

- Download the JDK from the Oracle website.
- Unpack it in /opt/jdk_17
- Create a link from /opt/jdk to /opt/jdk_17 (so every time I update the JDK I just need to update the link)
- Add JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk in /etc/environment
- Update (or add) PATH to include /opt/jdk/bin